# Lost between callback, request and promise

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I'm calling the google analytics API and trying to format the data I received from it on my server side before passing then to the front. Concretely I would like to use `promise`, to apply a `map` function on the response I have from the api call.

Here is my google analytics API call :

```
var datatable = function(req, res) {
  // authorize the client (see code above)
  authorize(function() {
    // do the actual call to the google api
    analytics.data.ga.get({
      'auth': jwtClient,
      'ids': VIEW_ID, 
      'metrics': 'ga:pageviews, ga:avgTimeOnPage',
      'dimensions': 'ga:contentGroup1, ga:searchDestinationPage',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
      'sort': '-ga:pageviews',
    }, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        // there was an error (unlikely, except you're trying to view a non-allowed view)
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      // send the data to the client (i.e. browser)
      res.send(response.rows);
    }); 
  });
}
```

I would like to apply the following map function `map( ([x, y, z]) => ({ x, y, z }) )` using a promise (I will have more transformation to apply later on). So I've tried something like this :

```
const formated_data = function(req, res) {
  return datatable()
   .then(function (response, error) {
    return res.send(response.map( ([x, y, z]) => ({ x, y, z }) )
});}
```

I've tried various thing but most of the time I have the following error : `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. From what I have understand I know that my api call doesn't return me a promise however I don't know how I should refactor it so it return me a promise.

I'm using express so at the end I need to export my data with `module.export` :

```
module.exports = {
    datatable
};
```

edit#1: I did read the answers from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) and many others and tried to apply some solutions. However I'm getting stuck with this `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. I understand why (my api call doesn't return a promise) but I don't know how to solve my issue.

Comment: If you are mapping a response (you already have the data) you don't need a promise.

Comment: I only took the mapping function as an illustration here. My main goal is to lear. Also, I need to apply multiple operation like sorting data, rollup and some math or time formatting. I want to use promise to chain the function with then.

Comment: Those operations are blocking. So you don't need a promise. You simply put them one after the other and they will execute in the right order. You use promises when doing some async operation (like fetching data from an API)

Comment: Show us how you tried to apply the solutions from the duplicate and we can reopen and help you.

Comment: well... based on my situation can someone tell me at least what are my callback so I can see what I need to convert as a promise. Just need some light. I've been reading and reading but I can't make the connection with my own code.